# how we use pageindiactor in pivot

Tags: windows-phone-7

i want to use page indicator control in pivot ,to show the user which page they attract.but i  also want to add some functionality in page indicator to select the page with the help of page indicator like android .but i don't know how it is possible.if u know then send me a link or example

Answer (score 0):

You could create the ui yourself and update the current page indicator by using the selectedIndex property. There are controls created by other developers, like [here](http://dotnet.dzone.com/news/windows-phone-7-pivot-page), which you could use. But for complete control over the functionality, I'd suggest you create your own or use the source code provided by other developers (see above link) to get ideas.

To make the implementation clearer:
You can add the same UIElement containing a list of dots equal to the number of pivots, and using the `SelectedIndex` property you can fill the corresponding dot. Add gesture events to this element and handle it to change the `SelectedIndex` appropriately.